# AVHapticPlayer async call finishWithCompletionHandler: (type=3) did not get a reply after 30 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, haptic-feedback, uifeedbackgenerator

### Problem

I am using **Haptic Feedback** in my app for when the user moves some tiles. When the tiles are moved very quickly, causing the haptic feedback to trigger quickly, I get this warning in the console after 30 seconds:

[image]

> 2019-01-20 17:29:04.658240+0000 Loopover[17824:4937487] [Feedback] AVHapticPlayer async call finishWithCompletionHandler: (type=3) did not get a reply after 30 seconds (notified of 0 mediaserverd death(s) in this time)

### How is the Haptic Feedback triggered?

I am triggering the Haptic Feedback using `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator` as shown:

```
UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
```

### What does this mean?

Is this warning something I should be worried about? If I move the tiles normally, no problems occur.

What should I do, if anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this warning something I should be worried about? What should I do, if anything?

I guess no, and none. In Apple's doc about **UIFeedbackGenerator** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator, they say you should "Trust the system" about that.

Talking about methods like `impactOccurred()`:

> Note that calling these methods does not play haptics directly.
>   Instead, it informs the system of the event. The system then
>   determines whether to play the haptics based on the device, the
>   application’s state, the amount of battery power remaining, and other
>   factors.

Haptic feedback is currently played only:

- On a device with a supported Taptic Engine
- When the app is running in the foreground
- When the System Haptics setting is enabled

And about the "Trust the system":

> As a general rule, trust the system to determine whether it should
>   play feedback. Don't check the device type or app state to
>   conditionally trigger feedback. After you’ve decided how you want to
>   use feedback, always trigger it when the appropriate events occur. The
>   system ignores any requests that it cannot fulfill.

I hope this helps!

Comment: My device fits all of the criteria, as you mentioned. Why would I still get this warning then? Is it just the system logging that it won't use haptic at that time (due to many being called)?

Comment: Ah! I made a quick sample that invokes `impactOccurred()` when the view is being dragged. Looks normal to me, the warnings are. I got `[Feedback] out of channels`, and `[Feedback] AVHapticPlayer async call finishWithCompletionHandler: still did not get a reply after one minute`. So for me, you should be fine. :)